# _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!ctktoplevel.!ctkentry2.!entry"?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I am trying to close a Top level window, when creating a new Toplevel window in customtkinter. I use `destroy()` at the end of the function to close it but  I get this error `_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!ctktoplevel.!ctkentry2.!entry"`.

Have look at some questions but they are about frames, buttons, labels, but haven't found the same error regarding a Toplevel window.

Can someone help me figure out how fix this pls?

Thank you in advance

```
def IDoptions(): #run first
    global idoptions,input1,input2
    idoptions = customtkinter.CTkToplevel(app, fg_color='#27333b')
    idoptions.geometry("430x400")  # size of window
    idoptions.title('Pulley Selection')  # tittle of the window
    # pselection.iconbitmap('Itipack_icon_cmyk_rev_l.ico')
    idoptions.resizable(False, False)
    app.attributes('-topmost', False)
    idoptions.attributes('-topmost', True)
    idoptions.after(201, lambda: 
    idoptions.iconbitmap('Itipack_icon_cmyk_rev_l.ico'))
    
    nextbutton = customtkinter.CTkButton(idoptions, width=100, height=28, text='Next', font=("Industry-Medium", 14),
                                           corner_radius=1, fg_color='#00AAE9',command=run_table)
    nextbutton.grid(row=20,column=2,padx=5,pady=5,sticky='e')



def run_table(): #run second

    currenth=380
    dashboard = customtkinter.CTkToplevel(app,fg_color='#27333b')
    dashboard.geometry(f"450x{currenth}") #size of window
    dashboard.title('Itipack Systems Cals') #tittle of the window
    dashboard.attributes('-topmost', True)  # note - before topmost
    dashboard.resizable(False, False)
    dashboard.after(201, lambda: dashboard.iconbitmap('Itipack_icon_cmyk_rev_l.ico'))
    
    idoptions.destroy()
```

Comment: You are trying to do something with an Entry - perhaps call `.get()` on it - after the containing Toplevel has been destroyed.  Given that the code you posted does not contain an Entry at all, it is clearly not a [mcve].

Comment: The updated code still does not have any code on `CTkEntry` widget.  Also it is better to post the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!ctktoplevel.!ctkentry2.!entry"` means that you are trying to destroy a widget that doesn't exist anymore. You should also drop the global variables and pass them around via function calls. This will help you discover flaws in your design more easily